# Get user that made the comment in facebooks instagram graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

Im building an application that manages comments for instagram business profiles, and i'm a little surprised that there doesn't seem to be a way to get info of the user who made the comment.

The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/comments/#reading) seem to point this way too:

> Reading a Comment
>
> To read an individual comment's metadata, send a GET request to the /{instagram_comment_id} node and include any of the following fields:
>
> ...
>
> **user (only returned if the user making the query also made the comment)**

So, am i to understand that there is no way to get the info of a user which made a comment on a media of the profile i manage or is there something i am missing? any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Comment: @bader you might wanna check my answer below

Comment: @bader sorry but no, didn't find a solution for this.

Comment: @bader i have updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

This url worked for me:

v3.0/{comment_id}?fields=id,timestamp,username,text

Comment: 6
down vote
accepted
Starting from Graph API v2.11, you need a page access token to get the (scoped) user_id from any endpoint (comments and reactions, for a start).

(See v2.11 90 Days Breaking Changes)

Comment: @A.J. working perfectly as of 10.0, so this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

somehow I was able to get the username from graph API, but I'm not getting the fields `name`, `profile_picture_url`, etc. this is my URL for getting the username.

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11
    /123?fields=mentioned_comment.comment_id(456){user{id, username}, text}
```

123 - instagram_business_account id

456 - comment id

You can get full user details from username by Calling Instagram API(Maybe it's against there privacy policy). suppose stackoverflow is the username, by calling this API you will get full data.

https://www.instagram.com/stackoverflow/?__a=1

Comment: thank you so much your you did great job digging facebook docs . Although I can't use it ...  your solution only works for mentions if it a regular comment then this request won't get any thing ..